# why is it not possible to do "import gtts.gTTS" whereas i can do "from gtts import gTTS" in python?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, google-speech-api, google-text-to-speech

[image: here is the screenshot of the error i got in python3]

The error says that the there is **no module named as "gtts.gTTS"**, and got this error many times while importing other modules. **So can you brief me what is the logic behind importing modules?** Can't we import class using "." operator?
What is the problem; I can't understand!

```
#what is the difference between these two codes
import gtts.gTTS
from gtts import gTTS
```

Comment: @Prune that's not true at all, the syntax is fine, if `gTTS` happened to be a module. From the error, it seems like it's actually a class, which you can't import in that way

Comment: @Prune you are absolutely wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike Java, where you do something like `import module.submodule.blah.blah.MyClass`, in Python, you can only directly import modules. If you want to only import a certain class, function, or other named value from a module, you need to use the `from ... import ...` syntax.

In all likelihood, `gtts` is a module, and `gTTS` is a class within that module. Therefore, `import gtts.gTTS` makes no sense, since `gTTS` isn't a module (that's what the error says), you must use `from gtts import gTTS`

For example, `import os.path` works fine, since `path` is a submodule of `os`, but if I wanted to use the `exists` function in `path`, I would need to use `from os.path import exists` or `import os.path; os.path.exists(...)`. I get a ModuleNotFoundError if I erroneously try `import os.path.exsts`.

Comment: Okay..i got your point but **how do i know whether i am importing class,function or any module without looking in the main directory of all the module** . Is there any method to check. _If we do "dir" then i will get all the attributes ,how will i know which is module or class or function_.